# Print entire struct in VS breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

Using Visual Studio 2008, I'd like to print the contents of a structure whenever a breakpoint is hit.

The debugger helpfully shortens the printed string so only the first three members are shown. Is there a way I can print the entire structure?

Comment: Add variable to Watch.  Click on the '+' sign to the left of the variable name to expand the contents.

Comment: I'll clarify: I need the contents printed to the output window, so I can run it through a script to look for a specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Turn breakpoint into [tracepoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). If there are a lot of members the tracepoint action will become long, but at least you have a solution.

Comment: That is precisely what I did. The output window shows `{dSymbolRate=0.00000000000000000 udwSamplingLength=0 bInvert=0 ...}`, but I need the other members as well.

Comment: @SimonRichter my suggestion was to print all the members manually.